# How to stub constructor

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, assertion

I am writing uni-test and tring to isolate my code as much as possible. I am using Mocha and chai for writing test and ES5 Syntax.
The problem is, I am not able to find any solution to stub constructor.

`Q.reject(new Error(obj.someFunction());`

In above example, I know how to test promise, how to stub my inner function, but how I can stub `Error` constructor? And how I can check `callWithExactly()`, etc.

`oStubSomeFunction = sinon.stub(obj, "someFunction")`

I am using for normal function. I didn't find any relevant example in [ChaiDocumentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/test/)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to stub the `Error` constructor you can use [the Node.js global namespace](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

code.js

```
exports.func = function() {
  return new Error('error message');
}
```

code.test.js

```
const { func } = require('./code');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('func', function () {
  it('should create an Error', function () {
    const errorStub = sinon.stub(global, 'Error');  // <= stub the global Error
    errorStub.callsFake(function(message) {  // <= use callsFake to create a mock constructor
      this.myMessage = 'stubbed: ' + message;
    });

    const result = func();

    errorStub.restore();  // <= restore Error before doing anything else

    assert(result.myMessage === 'stubbed: error message');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(errorStub, 'error message');  // Success!
  });
});
```

If you do this you'll want to restore `Error` before doing absolutely anything else...even assertions work using `Error` so the original `Error` needs to be in place in case an assertion fails.

---

It's a lot safer to just spy on `Error`:

```
const { func } = require('./code');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('func', function () {
  it('should create an Error', function () {
    const errorSpy = sinon.spy(global, 'Error');  // <= spy on the global Error
    func();
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(errorSpy, 'error message');  // Success!
    errorSpy.restore();
  });
});
```

---

...and ultimately there is a limit to how isolated code under test can get.  For something as low-level as `Error` you might want to look at leaving it completely intact and testing for a thrown `Error` using something like Chai's [`.throw`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) assertion.